# Searching on recyclerview with checkbox.After Searching my search checkbox selected but original list of checkbox of that position by default checked

Tags: checkbox, android-recyclerview

[I had searched the any item on recyclerview with checkbox -by deafault original list position bind after searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc0t5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selected item approach here. Use item selector boolean in your model class as shown below :

```
public class ItemModel {
    boolean isSelcted;

    public boolean isSelcted() {
        return isSelcted;
    }

    public void setSelcted(boolean selcted) {
        isSelcted = selcted;
    }
}
```

Now, when user select any checkbox then set the boolean value of selected item to true and then refresh the adapter like this.

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    for (ItemModel model : itemList) {
                        model.setSelcted(false);
                    }
                    model.setSelcted(true);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
```

Now search anything in your searchbox. If you are passing the same list in the searchList, then it will show the checked & unchecked checkboxes as expected.